# Is there a way to check if a list is a sublist of another list?

Tags: python

So say I have

```
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
y = [2,3,4]
```

Is there a way to check if `y` is in `x` exactly in the order that it's in?

so like an if statement that would be `true` if `y` is in `x`?

Comment: would `[2,3,6]` in `x` return `True`?